# Coefplot change bar colors

Tags: stata, coefplot

I am trying to change the color of bars when using `coefplot`.

I tried this:

```
mean reply, over(sample)
estimates store reply

coefplot reply, vertical recast(bar) barwidth(0.7) ciopts(recast(rcap) color(black)) citop format(%9.2f) legend(off)
```

`reply` and `sample` are both binary variables. I am trying to get one bar in one color and the other bar in a different color.

[I am getting this:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/enZgp.jpg)